# ignoring string values in countif formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have following countif formula which calculates the non empty cells in dynamic range.

```
=((COUNTIF((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(S4);COLUMN(S4))&":S"& 
 (MIN(IF(A4:A107="";ROW(A4:A107))))));"<>"&""))-1)
```

I want this formula to calculate only date filled cells.So if in my dynamic range, a cell does not include date but has string value in it, it should not be counted. You can see a sample from my sheet. Here  i want my formula to calculate only one date value and ignore the string values "N/A"[image]

How can i do this?

Comment: `=((COUNTIF((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(S4);COLUMN(S4))&":S"& 
 (MIN(IF(A4:A107="";ROW(A4:A107))))));"<>"&""&"N/A"))-1)` adding &"N/A" does not solve my fissue because it ignores then the blank cells

Comment: Does this work for you: `=COUNT(S4:INDEX(S4:S107,MIN(IF(A4:A107="",ROW(A4:A107)-3))))`

Comment: This might help you I guess, [Counts Only Date Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249662/excel-formula-count-cells-where-value-is-date )

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula if there's only Dates, Strings and Blanks.

```
=COUNTIF(range,">10000")
```

This might help you.